# production start constraint in yacc

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar, bison, yacc

I'm implementing a Javascript parser using Bison. The [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) states that

```
ExpressionStatement:
    [lookahead ∉ { '{' , 'function'}] Expression ;
```

That breaks the ambiguity between "{ }" as a BlockStatement (empty statement block) and as an ExpressionStatement (empty object literal) because an ExpressionStatement just can't start with a '{' token, although an Expression could.

Example of an empty statement block:

```
if (a > 5) {}
```

Example of an empty object literal:

```
var a = {};
```

How can I specify in a bison/yacc grammar that some production should not start with some particular tokens? I mean, something like:

```
expressionStatement
    : %must-not-start-with('{', TOKEN_FUNCTION) expression ';'
    ;
```

I know I could duplicate all my expression rules to define an "ExpressionNotStartingWithOpenCurlyBraceOrFunction", but that would increase a lot the size of my grammar, so I'm trying to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such directive in Bison.  I see two more options you could explore.  One would be to study the resulting conflict and see if you can resolve it using precedence directives (have a look at http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Shift_002fReduce.html).  Another would be to move to using a GLR parser, and resolve the ambiguity at runtime.

First option is probably easier, if applicable.  But that would depend a lot from your grammar.